# How to merge two collection of model and make it as one paginate then send it to the view in Laravel

Tags: laravel, view, model, controller, pagination

I want to send two collection model to view and make it as one paginate......but im still confused when i want to paginate as the two collection models

Here's my model RefHoliday.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RefHoliday extends Model
{
    //
    public $timestamps = false;

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $table = 'refHoliday';





}
```

second model -- HDHolidayCalendar.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class HDHolidayCalendar extends Model
{
    //
     public $timestamps = false;

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $table = 'Holiday_Calendar';

}
```

holiday controller

```
  public function index()
    {


          $refHol =  RefHoliday::all();
          $HolCal = HDHolidayCalendar::all();

        //  $paginationRecord = ??



         return view('administration.holiday.HolidayMasterList',  compact('??'));

    }
```

I try to explore to solve this things but seems not clearly explain...

Answer (score 0):

To merge two collection.

```
   $refHol =  RefHoliday::all();
   $holCal = HDHolidayCalendar::all();
   $data = $refHol->merge($holCal);
```

Comment: from $data how can i paginate ??

Comment: @adaminho Are these models related?

Comment: yes....after merge two model which is   $data = $refHol->merge($holCal); , how can i paginate from $data ??...

Comment: $data->forPage($_GET['page'], 5);

Comment: ref: [https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_forPage]